# SQL Server 2005: How to order a recordset when using the LIKE operator

Tags: sql-server-2005, union, sql-like, rank

Here is my problem. I have a select statement something like this:

```
select * from mytable where mycol like '%finance%'
```

The results look something like this:

```
id  mycol 
16  the finance department 
 8  i like the finance people 
43  chief finance officer 
22  finance 
68  finance trading
```

I would like to have the order come out like so:

```
id  mycol 
22  finance 
68  finance trading 
43  chief finance officer 
16  the finance department 
 8  i like the finance people
```

In essence, to have the select query use:

```
where mycol = 'finance'
```

then

```
where mycol = 'finance%'
```

then

```
where mycol = '%finance%'
```

1) I cannot use the id column for ordering purposes.

2) My query is far more complex than this (it's part of a paging a recordset on a large db using SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.category, t.sequence) ...

I'm thinking I might need to use UNION or RANK() or something, but I'm getting out of my league now. Any guidance greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The ranking will likely be better served via a Full-Text search function (CONTAINS, FREETEXT)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: ahh good catch! You're quite close to a mind reader, eh? :-)

Comment: @marc_s: Mind reader?  If only... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious solution:

```
Select Id, mycol
    , Case
        When mycol = 'finance' Then 1 
        When mycol Like 'finance%' Then 2
        When mycol Like '%finance%' Then 3
        End As Rnk
From MyTable
Where mycol Like '%finance%' 
Order By Rnk
```

Granted, this won't perform well with the leading and trailing wildcard. Another way would be to use full-text search which will give you a relevancy rank.

[CONTAINSTABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Your solution works well, but it's only part of my problem ... I'm using server side paging with ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) but the "rnk" column is flagged as invalid. I've opened up a new question regarding this issue ...